# Ionic 4 - Two way binding [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I'm struggling to use two way binding in Ionic 4. I used to use Ionic 3 and two way binding was super easy, I'm not sure why I'm struggling.

In my `app.module.ts` I import:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,
    RoundProgressModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
```

On my `.ts` file for my page, I simply init a variable:

```
user:any = { phone: '', name: '', date: '' }
```

and then I have a function I call to change the format of `user.phone`

```
formatNumber() {
    let num = this.user.phone;
    this.user.phone = new AsYouType('US').input(num) // a package to format numbers
    console.log(this.user.phone)
  }
```

the `console.log` produces the correct information, but it doesn't change in the `input` field..

My `.html` file looks like this:

```
 <form>
    <input class="phone-input" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" (ngModelChange)="formatNumber()" [(ngModel)]="user.phone">
 </form>
```

To me, that seems like it should all work... What am I doing wrong? It doesn't seem very obvious to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
<form>
    <input class="phone-input" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="(123) 456- 
    7890" (input)="formatNumber()" [(ngModel)]="user.phone">
</form>
```

`input` instead of `ngModelChange`.

Comment: Yes! That worked.. Do you know why that was the problem? Seems so strange.

Answer (score 0):

the correct use [ngModel] (ngModelChange) must be like

```
<input class="phone-input" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" 
    (ngModelChange)="formatNumber($event)" [ngModel]="user.phone">
```

See the $event as argument, and your function

```
formatNumber(num) { //<--see the argument
    this.user.phone = ....
    console.log(this.user.phone)
  }
```